# How or where can I get a 120VAC to 3.3VAC power supply?

Tags: power-supply, ac, gas

I'm using a safety gas valve (commonly found in household stoves) for a hobby project. The valve is rated for 3.3VAC, 3.6Amps. The problem is that AC-to-AC power supplies are quite rare, and I had no luck at all finding one that would match the rating above.

So my question is, how easy/doable would it be to take a AC-to-DC power supply with the above ratings and modify it to output AC voltage. Is it as simple as bypassing some internal components?

If not, then does anyone have ideas about where/how I could get the required power supply, or maybe if I could use some different method to open and close the gas valve?

**Edit:** Why all the downvotes? Did I ask this in the wrong place?

**Edit2:** I apologize for my lack of knowledge of EE terms. I don't really have much prior experience in EE.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "AC-to-DC transformer". All transformers are AC-to-AC.

Comment: Could you explain or post links please? As a programmer, I'm not at very experienced in EE.

Comment: [Transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer#Construction). [Wall wart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_adapter), *not* a transformer.

Comment: Do you have a link handy for the specifications of this valve? I suspect that "3.3 VAC" is a misprint of some sort.

Comment: I couldn't find any specs available online but the model# is AV24N04E and it says on the label: "3.3V.A.C. 3.6AMP. 60 Hz 1/2 P.S.I.  DO NOT APPLY 120 V.A.C. TO VALVE". The valve is supposed to be connected in series to an igniter which, as I understand, steps down 120VAC to the required 3.3VAC, while also generating a ton of heat and using up a ton of energy, which is why I need to somehow do without it.

Comment: This is more of a meta-answer than a real answer, which is why its here in the comments. Your original, unedited title was more accurate than you realised. A 120Vac to 3.3Vac *transformer* is in fact *exactly* what you need. The problem you introduced in your edits was in the common confusion between "transformer" and "power supply" resulting from the application of both names to what we colloquially call "wall-warts". The most likely reason for all of the down-votes is that this really amounts to little more than a shopping question - and these are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a transformer with a 117 volt primary, 3.3 volt secondary, and at least 4 amp current. You can't get this, exactly, but a standard 220 / 6.3 volt transformer connected to 120 VAC will give you a nominal 3.15 volts, which should be close enough.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So something like [this](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/1pcs-High-quality-30VA-Transformer-IN-0-110-220V-OUT-230-0-230-6-3V-6/1683043895.html) would work, right? Just want to make sure.  Also, any idea why this question got so many downvotes here?

Comment: That's the right idea, but the 6.3 volt outputs do not have sufficient current capacity. In this particular case, you're paying for a lot of unneeded isolated 110/220 output as well as the voltage you need. I suspect that people were annoyed that you don't know the difference between a transformer and a power supply, and thought you should have done more research.

Comment: Thanks for the catch, I saw that the transformer was rated 30VA and didn't notice that this output power was actually divided among the different outputs. Since this will be connected to 120V, anything with 2A or higher rated capacity on the 6.3V line will be good right?